# OPCItem.Additem fails to add items, OPC Foundation

Tags: c#, opc-ua

i have a service that reads data from an API and put this information into OPC,
I'm using OPC-foundation Framework.

i can connect to OPC, I can add Group and when i try to add Items to the group i doesn't success.  It returns error to the error parameters that i send in but with no error description,  But is seems that the function OPItem.AddItems  doesn't success

Here is the code that i run.

```
 public bool AddOPCItems(int itemCount, ref List<Vehicles> vehicles)
    {

            bool itemsAdded = false;

            try
            {
                // Size of array must be number of parameters plus one
                // since array index starts at 0 and OPC reads/writes array starting at 1
                int size = (vehicles.Count * ventObjReadProp.Length + 1);
                Array OPCItemIDs = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(string), size);
                Array clientHandles = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(int), size);
                Array itemServerErrors = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(int), size);
                int index = 1;

             itemServerHandles = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(int), size);

                for (int n = 0; n < vehicles.Count; n++) //Loop all ventObj
                {
                    //_log.Log("Adding Object= " + n + " of " + vehicles.Count, "", LogType.Main);
                    for (int i = 0; i < ventObjReadProp.Length; i++) //Loop trough all the properties in each ventObj
                    {
                        string item = vehicles.ElementAt(n).OpcTag + ventObjReadProp[i];
                        OPCItemIDs.SetValue(item, index);
                        clientHandles.SetValue(index, index);
                    //if (i == 0) { UGMLogFile.addToLogFile("Add item: " + item + " at index " + index); }
                    _log.Log("Adding Object= " + n + " of " + vehicles.Count + ":  "+ item, "", LogType.Main);
                    index++;
                    }
                }

                index = 0;
                _OPCGroup.OPCItems.DefaultIsActive = true;
            _log.Log("Nr of OPCItemIDs --> " + OPCItemIDs.Length, "", LogType.Main);
            _log.Log("Before: _OPCGroup.OPCItems --> " + _OPCGroup.OPCItems.Count, "", LogType.Main);
            _OPCGroup.OPCItems.AddItems(size - 1, ref OPCItemIDs, ref clientHandles, out itemServerHandles, out itemServerErrors);
            _log.Log("After: _OPCGroup.OPCItems --> " + _OPCGroup.OPCItems.Count, "", LogType.Main);

            if (itemServerHandles != null && itemServerHandles.Length > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 1; i <= itemServerHandles.Length; i++)
                {
                    _log.Log("Error from itemServerHandles --> " + itemServerHandles.GetValue(i), "", LogType.Main);
                }
            }
            itemsAdded = true;

                _log.Log("AddOPCReadVentObjItems: " + "Added items = " + _OPCGroup.OPCItems.Count.ToString() + " XML config = " + (size - 1), "", LogType.Main);

            if (itemServerErrors.Length > 1)
            {
                _log.Log("", "", LogType.Main);
            }
                   // UGMLogFile.addToLogFile("AddOPCReadVentObjItems: " + itemServerErrors.ToString());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _log.Log(ex.Message, "", LogType.Main);
            }
            return itemsAdded;            
    }
```

here is the infromation from log file where we can see the information that the function tries to add.

```
  Connected to OPC
2023-11-29 02:34 PM             Connected to ---> True
2023-11-29 02:34 PM             Group added
2023-11-29 02:34 PM             BEFORE THE LOOP
2023-11-29 02:34 PM             numOfObjects 6
2023-11-29 02:34 PM             item -->: Root/Smart Mid/Mina_Pastefill/Applicatoin/VoDMLI_App/MobilarisZoneTranslation:MEStorage.MobileEquipment1
2023-11-29 02:34 PM             item -->: Root/Smart Mid/Mina_Pastefill/Applicatoin/VoDMLI_App/MobilarisZoneTranslation:MEStorage.MobileEquipment2
2023-11-29 02:34 PM             item -->: Root/Smart Mid/Mina_Pastefill/Applicatoin/VoDMLI_App/MobilarisZoneTranslation:MEStorage.MobileEquipment3
2023-11-29 02:34 PM             item -->: Root/Smart Mid/Mina_Pastefill/Applicatoin/VoDMLI_App/MobilarisZoneTranslation:MEStorage.MobileEquipment4
2023-11-29 02:34 PM             item -->: Root/Smart Mid/Mina_Pastefill/Applicatoin/VoDMLI_App/MobilarisZoneTranslation:MEStorage.MobileEquipment5
2023-11-29 02:34 PM             item -->: Root/Smart Mid/Mina_Pastefill/Applicatoin/VoDMLI_App/MobilarisZoneTranslation:MEStorage.MobileEquipment6
2023-11-29 02:34 PM             Before AddOPCItems, ventObjList.Count is:  6
2023-11-29 02:34 PM             Adding Object= 0 of 6:  Root/Smart Mid/Mina_Pastefill/Applicatoin/VoDMLI_App/MobilarisZoneTranslation:MEStorage.MobileEquipment1.Name
2023-11-29 02:34 PM             Adding Object= 0 of 6:  Root/Smart Mid/Mina_Pastefill/Applicatoin/VoDMLI_App/MobilarisZoneTranslation:MEStorage.MobileEquipment1.LocationData.LocationName
2023-11-29 02:34 PM             Adding Object= 0 of 6:  Root/Smart Mid/Mina_Pastefill/Applicatoin/VoDMLI_App/MobilarisZoneTranslation:MEStorage.MobileEquipment1.LocationData.Timestamp
2023-11-29 02:34 PM             Adding Object= 0 of 6:  Root/Smart Mid/Mina_Pastefill/Applicatoin/VoDMLI_App/MobilarisZoneTranslation:MEStorage.MobileEquipment1.LocationData.Macaddress
2023-11-29 02:34 PM             Adding Object= 1 of 6:  Root/Smart Mid/Mina_Pastefill/Applicatoin/VoDMLI_App/MobilarisZoneTranslation:MEStorage.MobileEquipment2.Name
2023-11-29 02:34 PM             Adding Object= 1 of 6:  Root/Smart Mid/Mina_Pastefill/Applicatoin/VoDMLI_App/MobilarisZoneTranslation:MEStorage.MobileEquipment2.LocationData.LocationName
2023-11-29 02:34 PM             Adding Object= 1 of 6:  Root/Smart Mid/Mina_Pastefill/Applicatoin/VoDMLI_App/MobilarisZoneTranslation:MEStorage.MobileEquipment2.LocationData.Timestamp
2023-11-29 02:34 PM             Adding Object= 1 of 6:  Root/Smart Mid/Mina_Pastefill/Applicatoin/VoDMLI_App/MobilarisZoneTranslation:MEStorage.MobileEquipment2.LocationData.Macaddress
2023-11-29 02:34 PM             Adding Object= 2 of 6:  Root/Smart Mid/Mina_Pastefill/Applicatoin/VoDMLI_App/MobilarisZoneTranslation:MEStorage.MobileEquipment3.Name
2023-11-29 02:34 PM             Adding Object= 2 of 6:  Root/Smart Mid/Mina_Pastefill/Applicatoin/VoDMLI_App/MobilarisZoneTranslation:MEStorage.MobileEquipment3.LocationData.LocationName
2023-11-29 02:34 PM             Adding Object= 2 of 6:  Root/Smart Mid/Mina_Pastefill/Applicatoin/VoDMLI_App/MobilarisZoneTranslation:MEStorage.MobileEquipment3.LocationData.Timestamp
2023-11-29 02:34 PM             Adding Object= 2 of 6:  Root/Smart Mid/Mina_Pastefill/Applicatoin/VoDMLI_App/MobilarisZoneTranslation:MEStorage.MobileEquipment3.LocationData.Macaddress
2023-11-29 02:34 PM             Adding Object= 3 of 6:  Root/Smart Mid/Mina_Pastefill/Applicatoin/VoDMLI_App/MobilarisZoneTranslation:MEStorage.MobileEquipment4.Name
2023-11-29 02:34 PM             Adding Object= 3 of 6:  Root/Smart Mid/Mina_Pastefill/Applicatoin/VoDMLI_App/MobilarisZoneTranslation:MEStorage.MobileEquipment4.LocationData.LocationName
2023-11-29 02:34 PM             Adding Object= 3 of 6:  Root/Smart Mid/Mina_Pastefill/Applicatoin/VoDMLI_App/MobilarisZoneTranslation:MEStorage.MobileEquipment4.LocationData.Timestamp
2023-11-29 02:34 PM             Adding Object= 3 of 6:  Root/Smart Mid/Mina_Pastefill/Applicatoin/VoDMLI_App/MobilarisZoneTranslation:MEStorage.MobileEquipment4.LocationData.Macaddress
2023-11-29 02:34 PM             Adding Object= 4 of 6:  Root/Smart Mid/Mina_Pastefill/Applicatoin/VoDMLI_App/MobilarisZoneTranslation:MEStorage.MobileEquipment5.Name
2023-11-29 02:34 PM             Adding Object= 4 of 6:  Root/Smart Mid/Mina_Pastefill/Applicatoin/VoDMLI_App/MobilarisZoneTranslation:MEStorage.MobileEquipment5.LocationData.LocationName
2023-11-29 02:34 PM             Adding Object= 4 of 6:  Root/Smart Mid/Mina_Pastefill/Applicatoin/VoDMLI_App/MobilarisZoneTranslation:MEStorage.MobileEquipment5.LocationData.Timestamp
2023-11-29 02:34 PM             Adding Object= 4 of 6:  Root/Smart Mid/Mina_Pastefill/Applicatoin/VoDMLI_App/MobilarisZoneTranslation:MEStorage.MobileEquipment5.LocationData.Macaddress
2023-11-29 02:34 PM             Adding Object= 5 of 6:  Root/Smart Mid/Mina_Pastefill/Applicatoin/VoDMLI_App/MobilarisZoneTranslation:MEStorage.MobileEquipment6.Name
2023-11-29 02:34 PM             Adding Object= 5 of 6:  Root/Smart Mid/Mina_Pastefill/Applicatoin/VoDMLI_App/MobilarisZoneTranslation:MEStorage.MobileEquipment6.LocationData.LocationName
2023-11-29 02:34 PM             Adding Object= 5 of 6:  Root/Smart Mid/Mina_Pastefill/Applicatoin/VoDMLI_App/MobilarisZoneTranslation:MEStorage.MobileEquipment6.LocationData.Timestamp
2023-11-29 02:34 PM             Adding Object= 5 of 6:  Root/Smart Mid/Mina_Pastefill/Applicatoin/VoDMLI_App/MobilarisZoneTranslation:MEStorage.MobileEquipment6.LocationData.Macaddress
2023-11-29 02:34 PM             Nr of OPCItemIDs --> 25
2023-11-29 02:34 PM             Before: _OPCGroup.OPCItems --> 0
2023-11-29 02:34 PM             After: _OPCGroup.OPCItems --> 0
2023-11-29 02:34 PM             Error from itemServerHandles --> 0
2023-11-29 02:34 PM             Error from itemServerHandles --> 0
2023-11-29 02:34 PM             Error from itemServerHandles --> 0
2023-11-29 02:34 PM             Error from itemServerHandles --> 0
2023-11-29 02:34 PM             Error from itemServerHandles --> 0
2023-11-29 02:34 PM             Error from itemServerHandles --> 0
2023-11-29 02:34 PM             Error from itemServerHandles --> 0
2023-11-29 02:34 PM             Error from itemServerHandles --> 0
2023-11-29 02:34 PM             Error from itemServerHandles --> 0
2023-11-29 02:34 PM             Error from itemServerHandles --> 0
2023-11-29 02:34 PM             Error from itemServerHandles --> 0
2023-11-29 02:34 PM             Error from itemServerHandles --> 0
2023-11-29 02:34 PM             Error from itemServerHandles --> 0
2023-11-29 02:34 PM             Error from itemServerHandles --> 0
2023-11-29 02:34 PM             Error from itemServerHandles --> 0
2023-11-29 02:34 PM             Error from itemServerHandles --> 0
2023-11-29 02:34 PM             Error from itemServerHandles --> 0
2023-11-29 02:34 PM             Error from itemServerHandles --> 0
2023-11-29 02:34 PM             Error from itemServerHandles --> 0
2023-11-29 02:34 PM             Error from itemServerHandles --> 0
2023-11-29 02:34 PM             Error from itemServerHandles --> 0
2023-11-29 02:34 PM             Error from itemServerHandles --> 0
2023-11-29 02:34 PM             Error from itemServerHandles --> 0
2023-11-29 02:34 PM             Error from itemServerHandles --> 0
2023-11-29 02:34 PM             AddOPCReadVentObjItems: Added items = 0 XML config = 24
2023-11-29 02:34 PM             
2023-11-29 02:34 PM             Before Write to OPC
2023-11-29 02:34 PM             _OPCGroup Name -->Vehicles
2023-11-29 02:34 PM             _OPCGroup items-->System.__ComObject
2023-11-29 02:34 PM             itemCount -->0
2023-11-29 02:34 PM             Try To get syncItemValues.GetValue(i)-->
2023-11-29 02:34 PM             Errors -->Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

enter code here

enter code here

enter code here

enter code here
```